# Image bleed when using Import Image as Plane

Tags: image

I'm working on an project where I need to import some graphics that I created. I'm able to import them fine using the `Import Images as Planes` plugin.

They look totally fine when in the Material viewport shading type:

[image]

However, as soon as I go to render it out, I get these strange speckles along the sides and top:

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.76, hash 477078b and from what I can tell it's the image bleeding over the edge of the plane to the other side, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Does anyone know what's causing this and how I could fix it?

Comment: This happened to me in Illustrator CS6. When you export the image make sure you check "Use Artboards"; otherwise, it will crop it down to fit around your image and give you those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you to be right as for the cause of the problem. I can see two easy ways to solve it:

- Scale the geometry down in the UV Image Editor and live a happy life ever after.
- If you actually need to presicely fit the plane to the image, add a blank (as in zero-alpha) border around your image in your favourite image editor (1px should do it.)

Comment: Sorry if this is gibberish